# Usage of CSS in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I am just trying to make the following html code as a lightning component, but not getting the output as it is.
I tried to keep html part(the div and span elements) in lightning component, javascript functions in lightning controller and css in style but somehow it is not working. The html code(that I am trying to convert to a lightning component)  is at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay2.
Can you please let me know how to make a lightning component with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  background-color: turquoise;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  
  <div class="overlay-content">    
    Help Content
  </div>
</div>
 
<span style="float:right;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer"  onclick="openNav()"> help</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want this in Aura or LWC? Just double-checking.

Comment: I am trying this in Aura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert this to Aura, we need a few tweaks.

## `id` is not supported

We need to change it to aura:id:

```
<div aura:id="myNav" class="overlay">
```

## CSS needs `.THIS`

We need to scope our CSS, so we need to add a few `.THIS` selectors:

```css
.THIS {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.THIS.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  background-color: turquoise;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.THIS .overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.THIS.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.THIS.overlay a:hover,
.THIS.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.THIS.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .THIS.overlay {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .THIS.overlay a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .THIS.overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

Note that we use a space if the element is not a top-level element, and no space otherwise (e.g. `.THIS.overlay` because it is a top-level element, and `.THIS .overlay-content` because it is contained inside another element).

## Direct JavaScript is not supported

We need to change the event handlers to support Aura calls:

```
    <a href="#" class="closebtn" onclick="{!c.closeNav}">&times;</a>
```

And:

```
    <span style="float:right;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="{!c.openNav}">
```

Finally, we need to put the methods in a controller. We use `component.find` to get the SecureComponent that is the overlay, then then we need to `getElement()` to reach in to the DOM.

```
({
  openNav: function (component, event, helper) {
    component.find("myNav").getElement().style.height = "100%";
  },
  closeNav: function (component, event, helper) {
    component.find("myNav").getElement().style.height = "0%";
  },
});
```

I may have overlooked a few details, as I haven't loaded the actual code from w3schools, but this should be a close approximation.

Here's the final component:

```
<aura:component>
    <div aura:id="myNav" class="overlay">
        <a href="#" class="closebtn" onclick="{!c.closeNav}">&times;</a>

        <div class="overlay-content">
            Help Content
        </div>
    </div>

    <span style="float:right;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="{!c.openNav}">
        help
    </span>

</aura:component>
```

---

```
({ // This is the controller //
  openNav: function (component, event, helper) {
    component.find("myNav").getElement().style.height = "100%";
  },
  closeNav: function (component, event, helper) {
    component.find("myNav").getElement().style.height = "0%";
  },
})
```

---

```
.THIS {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.THIS.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  background-color: turquoise;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.THIS .overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.THIS.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.THIS.overlay a:hover,
.THIS.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.THIS.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .THIS.overlay {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .THIS.overlay a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .THIS.overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```